# Add author to a newly created node

Tags: 8, rules

When users sign up, I create a new node and add that user into one of the entity reference fields through rules.

What I built so far is the following.

1. *After saving a new user* event
2. *Create a new content item* action (Parameters: type: advisor_student_matching_program, title: title comes here)
3. *Set a data value* (Parameters: data: node_created.field_university_student, value: @user.current_user_context:current_user)
4. *Save entity* (Parameters: entity: node_created, immediate: 1)

Everything works fine except for the third step.

```yaml
uuid: 692696f4-4c6d-45cc-8a5b-3b69f1925bd0
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies: {  }
id: register_university_student
label: 'Register University Student'
events:
  -
    event_name: 'rules_entity_insert:user'
description: ''
tags: {  }
config_version: '3'
expression:
  id: rules_rule
  uuid: 6f4c1ccb-973c-48ec-aed1-637bdb50e301
  weight: 0
  conditions:
    id: rules_and
    uuid: 3f479a19-06b2-4e05-80c2-4cff28650409
    weight: 0
    conditions: {  }
  actions:
    id: rules_action_set
    uuid: abbb62e5-a610-4ab7-8e3a-f96a4570f049
    weight: 0
    actions:
      -
        id: rules_action
        uuid: 3bce44f5-accb-4239-9c1d-377f29debebf
        weight: 0
        context_values:
          type: advisor_student_matching_program
          title: 'title comes here'
        context_mapping: {  }
        context_processors:
          type:
            rules_tokens: {  }
          title:
            rules_tokens: {  }
        provides_mapping: {  }
        action_id: 'rules_entity_create:node'
      -
        id: rules_action
        uuid: eba88823-1ab3-493a-9b62-e22e49a2db4a
        weight: 0
        context_values: {  }
        context_mapping:
          data: node_created.field_university_student
          value: '@user.current_user_context:current_user'
        context_processors: {  }
        provides_mapping: {  }
        action_id: rules_data_set
      -
        id: rules_action
        uuid: 779eadc9-f208-4cfa-b37e-351126c56243
        weight: 0
        context_values:
          immediate: '1'
        context_mapping:
          entity: node_created
        context_processors:
          immediate:
            rules_tokens: {  }
        provides_mapping: {  }
        action_id: rules_entity_save
      -
        id: rules_action
        uuid: 18d0c0d6-d9c6-4fc9-8127-4291fe80081c
        weight: 0
        context_values:
          url: /register-uni-basic-information
        context_mapping: {  }
        context_processors:
          url:
            rules_tokens: {  }
        provides_mapping: {  }
        action_id: rules_page_redirect
```

Answer (score 1):

Should have used `user`, instead of `@user.current_user_context:current_user`.